# USB Scale not showing up using WebHID

Tags: google-chrome, usb, hid, webusb, webhid

I have a USB scale of type Mettler/Toledo PS60 which I'm trying to connect to using the WebHID API in order to receive scale values for my web app. However it doesn't show up in the list of devices when calling requestDevice().

```
navigator.hid.requestDevice({ filters: [] })
```

The device DOES show up when using the WebUSB API however I can't connect to it with error message "The requested interface implements a protected class." Ok makes sense since the interface shows as HID and "blocked by WebUSB" in chrome://usb-internals/ but then why doesn't it show up when using WebHID?

[image]

I tried changing drivers to WinUSB but that didn't seem to make any difference. Anyone have a clue as to what the issue is or some way I can get more information about why the device is not listed? Or is it simply not possible to use this device with WebHID/WebUSB?

Comment: Check chrome://device-log to see if the device was detected as an HID device. Make sure to uncheck "USB" so you only see logs from the HID subsystem. Also check the JavaScript console for any warnings when you call `navigator.hid.requestDevice()`.

Comment: It only shows up in the device log with the USB tag. There are no warnings in the console for navigator.hid.requestDevice().

Comment: @ReillyGrant I noticed the device is using USB version 1.1.0. Is that perhaps too old to work with WebHID? My keyboard with 2.0 shows up just fine.

Comment: The USB HID protocol works over USB 1.1. You must have a fancy keyboard for it to be USB 2.0. What platform are you on? We've seen some issues with Chrome discovering HID devices on Windows if the system recognizes them as a keyboard rather than a generic HID device and therefore doesn't expose them through the necessary userspace APIs.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: When you connect the device what does the USB tagged event say in the "driver=" property?

Comment: By default it shows driver="libusb0" however I've also tried changing drivers to WinUSB in which case it shows driver="WinUSB" (sorry for late reply)

Comment: That explains it. You probably have a native Windows app installed which included an INF file telling Windows to load that driver. For the device to work with WebHID you want to load the default Windows HID driver. Zadig should have an option for that.

Comment: Hm.. The only options in Zadig are "USB Serial", "WinUSB", "libusb-win32" and "libusbK". I tried uninstalling from device manager and replugging it which defaulted to libusb.

Comment: You can use the "Update driver" option in device manager to switch drivers as well. You just need to find the generic USB HID driver in Windows's list of all possible drivers.